# Locked hard drive Eee pc 1005 HAB

Tags: bios, eee-pc, password-recovery, hard-drive-recovery

I have a Eee pc 1005 HAB that has a locked hard drive.  I don't have a password for it or the master password.  I was told i could take up the battery for the BIOS and put it back in to reset it but I can't get the case open!  Where is the BIoS battery located?  How do these clips work?

Comment: If it's locked at firmware level, removing the CMOS battery won't help.